# SharedPreferences behaviour on Update/Uninstall

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am using shared preferences to store the number of times my application has been launched. Only on the first launch i display an Welcome message telling the user about the new features and changes in that version.

But as i absorbed on reinstalling the app or upgrading the application i am not able to remove the previous shared preferences. i would like to get the dialog when i reinstall the software or upgrade it too.

AppLauncher

```
public class AppLauncher {
    static long launch_count = 0;
    private static boolean isLaunch = false;

    public static void app_launched(Context mContext) {
        System.out.println("I m in AppLauncher");
        SharedPreferences prefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences("apprater", 0);
        if (prefs.getBoolean("dontshowagain", false)) {
            return;
        }

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

        // Increment launch counter

        launch_count = prefs.getLong("launch_count", 0);
        editor.putLong("launch_count", launch_count);

        System.out.println("launch_count=" + launch_count);
        if (launch_count == 0 || launch_count == 1) {
            // showLaunchDialog(mContext);
            isLaunch = true;
        }
        if (isLaunch == true) {
            showLaunchDialog(mContext);
            isLaunch = false;
        }
        editor.commit();
    }

    public static void showLaunchDialog(Context mcontext) {
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(mcontext);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.whatsnew);

        Button dismisButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dismisButtom);
        System.out.println("inside dialog_started");
        dismisButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        dialog.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: how have you first created sharedPreference..

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is no hook that you can use to erase the shared preferences in the case of an update.

Nikolay is right you can save the version number of your app. And compare it with the current version number.

To obtain the current version number call:

```
this.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(this.getPackageName(), 0).versionCode
```

For more info on what information is available in the package info read the Documentation on the [PackageInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageInfo.html#versionCode) and the [PackageManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html).

Comment: Thanks for elaborating with more information :) i think this is what i need ;)

Answer (score 13):

Instead of saving a `boolean` save the version number of the app. If the current app's version  number is higher (updated), show your dialog and update the number.

Comment: Though the solution is simple, I would expect Android SDK to add a simple hook like for DB upgrade to avoid lots of upgrade bugs and increase robustness (for example one could forget about this pref and clear the preferences at some point...)

Answer (score 1):

If you get don't set dontShowagin you will get false by default .So you want to show dialog and next time not.So just change the value in preference to true so that next time it works.Also you are incrementing the counter without actually incrementing it.Use +1 with the previous one.

```
SharedPreferences prefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences("apprater", 0);
            if (prefs.getBoolean("dontshowagain", false)) {
                return;
            }

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

            // Increment launch counter

            editor.putBoolean("dontShowagain",true);
            launch_count = prefs.getLong("launch_count", 0)+1;
            editor.putLong("launch_count", launch_count);
```

Comment: This won't solve the problem of showing the dialog again after an app update.

Answer (score 1):

try to listen this Intents:

```
ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED
ACTION_PACKAGE_CHANGED
ACTION_PACKAGE_DATA_CLEARED
ACTION_PACKAGE_FIRST_LAUNCH
ACTION_PACKAGE_INSTALL  
ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED  
ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED 
ACTION_PACKAGE_RESTARTED
```

more on: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED