# Clear Old Preference in Android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, google-play

In my previous android application release i was using default shared preference.But now i'm using my own app specific preference to store data.I want to clear old preference from all installed application using play store app release update.
Any suggestions

Comment: SharedPreferences.Editor.clear().commit();

Comment: I know this but how to clear data from the users who already have the application.

Comment: for those users clearing will only happen after app update after adding my code below. there is no other way

Comment: i got the solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7103453/sharedpreferences-update-unisntall

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("myPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();//type the old preference file name
    editor.clear().commit();
```